# iPhone Simulator Swiping not working properly

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode10

Using the latest version of xcode, 10.1, and ios 12 simulators, for some of the simulators, like the new iphones with the curved screen, the swipe gesterue only registers once I lift the click from the screen. With simulators like iPhone SE and iPhone 6s, swiping around works fine. Is there a fix?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "lift the click from the screen"? Exactly how are you doing the swipe?

Comment: normally, as you would intuitively expect with the mouse. the iphone xr specifically has this problem, not the xs max

Comment: There is a known bug with the XR where performance while processing input is poor; it is possible the issue you are seeing is a result of that.

Comment: yes, it is probably that, but it happens on a few other older devices too. Good to know its a known bug, that answers the question.